# Ajax function with laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to use the ajax function (load) to load pages in my laravel. Here is my html code

```
@section('content')

<nav class="" id="menu">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="sub_menu"> 
        <li class="active"><a href="pages/home">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="pages/school">Create School</a></li> 
        <li><a href="pages/user">Create User</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</nav> <div id="page_loader"></div>
@endsection
```

Here is my controller Code

```
Route::get('pages/user', ['uses' => 'businessController@getCreateUser', 'as' => 'business.pages.user']);
Route::get('pages/school', ['uses' => 'businessController@getCreateSchool', 'as' => 'business.pages.school']);
Route::get('pages/business', ['uses' => 'businessController@getBusiness', 'as' => 'business.pages.home']);
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ var trigger = $('#menu #sub_menu li a'), content = $('#page_loader');    
    trigger.on('click', function(){ 
        var $this = $(this), target = $this.attr('href'); 
        content.load(target); 
        return false; 
    });    
});
```

The error displaying on my page console is :

> jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/pages/pages/home 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This looks like a simple case of confusing relative and absolute paths. Where do you think you end up clicking on `<a href="pages/home">` if you're already viewing http://localhost/pages/?

Answer (score 0):

You're using relative references in your navigation links so if you're at  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/pages/` then any link like `pages/home` will direct you to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/pages/pages/home`

Use laravel's helpers instead:

```
@section('content')

<nav class="" id="menu">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="sub_menu"> 
        <li class="active"><a href="{{url()->to("pages/home")}}">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="{{url()->to("pages/school")}}">Create School</a></li> 
        <li><a href="{{url()->to("pages/user")}}">Create User</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</nav> <div id="page_loader"></div>
@endsection
```

This way Laravel takes care of things for you.